# Print 4 auto-filtered columns in portrait on same page

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I need to print everything from A1 to D-as many rows until a blank row in my auto-filtered spreadsheet. The only way I can do it manually is using print selection but I don't want to do that. here is my code so far:

```
Sub PrintTest()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
        
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    lastRow = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    ' Set up the printing page
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
      With ws.PageSetup
          .Orientation = xlPortrait
          .Zoom = False
          .FitToPagesWide = 1
          .FitToPagesTall = False
          .PrintArea = ws.Range("A1:D" & lastRow).Address
      End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True

    ' Show the print dialog
    'Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
    ActiveWorkbook.PrintOut Copies:=2, Preview:=True, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    
End Sub
```

Right now when I run it and do a print preview, I get every column instead of A-D. I think the code looks good but I can't figure out what is happening. I'm running Excel 2016. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Strange - code works for me, tested with 2016 and 365. Tried with different ranges.

Comment: How many columns of data did you put in? I have up to AV. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Testsheet with 6 columns.